p5.js stuck in preload() displaying default of "loading..."
I simply tried to import an asset to my p5.js project. I tried it with different asset files and also with an empty preload().
Every time I run the project it gets stuck in the preload() and displaying "loading...".
I tried it with a local server and the go live function. Also events like mouse clicking to initiate doesn't work. Also I tried it with instancing as I read that there are problems between p5.js and npm, but that also didn't work.
Console is showing nothing.
let quote = "hi";
let font; 

function preload() {
  font = loadFont("/Users/stefan/Desktop/Design/P5/good_evil_overcome/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
  rectMode(CENTER);

  textFont(font);
  textSize(windowWidth/25);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  text(quote, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);

}

function draw() {

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I tried:

Different asset types .mp3, font files.
Running a local http server and go live function
instancing
updating npm version, http server


Console or network requests should show an error if something didn't load. You'll need a local HTTP server to access local files, which means your URL will look something like localhost:8000/Montserrat-Regular.ttf, or Montserrat-Regular.ttf if you're also running the sketch on the same server.

See The page is stuck on "Loading..." when using preload() in "p5.js"--likely the same issue even though you're loading a font rather than a png.

Are you sure the project code is being saved properly? An empty preload() should never block forever. Or try removing preload() to see if that unblocks you.
